# KVM Service Container on CRS 1000v?

Tags: cisco

Does the CRS 1000v support KVM service containers? I opened a case with Cisco Partner Helpline, and according to the BU the answer is yes. However the router seems to disagree:

```
Router#show virtual-service 
Virtual Service Global State and Virtualization Limits:
...
Machine types supported   : LXC
Machine types disabled    : KVM
```

And when I try to activate a KVM OVA that I installed it generates this log message:

```
%VMAN-3-GENERAL_FAILURE: F0: vman:  Virtual Service[SCDemoVM]::Activate::Internal error::Machine type 'kvm' is not supported
```

Router version is 16.03.01 (Denali).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Make sure that you have nested virtualization enabled in your
>   hypervisor. VMWare calls this VHV or Virtual Hardware-Assisted
>   Virtualization and your CPU also has to support it. Other hypervisors
>   call it different things. You also need to make sure that you have
>   support for unsigned 3rd party KVM applications configured on the CSR.
>   That would be the signing-level command under virtual-service.
>
> Finally, this is only available in IOS-XE 3.17 or later.   While
>   support for KVM inside of the CSR is supported, it isn't always a good
>   idea for actual deployment. You're running a virtual machine inside of
>   a virtual machine so performance is going to suffer. However, it does
>   make a great development sandbox for getting things working. You can
>   find more info in DevNet at https://developer.cisco.com/site/kvm

[SOURCE](https://communities.cisco.com/thread/71023?start=0&tstart=0)

> Linux, yes, but the only interface with the system is via IOSd.
>
> Because IOSd is running as a discrete process it has protected memory
>   that is isolated from crashes in other processes and failures in other
>   components in the system.
>
> #### Problem: Can I run my App inside a Router ?
>
> #### Solution: Yes !
>
> - From IOS XE3.17 onwards
> - Option to enable unsigned containers
> - Any 3rd party KVM
> - Libvirt based format / YAML manifest file
> - Requires 4GB+ dedicated RAM
> - ASR1000, ISR4000, **CSR1000**
>
> `virtual-service install name myapp package flash:myapp.ova show
>   virtual-service list show virtual-service detail name myapp
>   virtual-service connect name myapp aux|console`
>
> [image]

[SOURCE](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/global/hr_hr/events/2016/cisco-connect/pdf/Cisco_IOS_XE_Routers_-_ASR_1000_and_ISR_4000_-_The_Evolution_of_Converged_Network_Edge_Architectures_-_Jaromir_Pila_Cisco.pdf)

Comment: You are correct, I needed to enable nested virtualization in my hypervisor. Once I did that a `show virtual-service` reports `Machine types supported   : KVM, LXC`.